# SQL join tables with wildcard (MS Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access

how do i join following tables with wildcards? I would like to get all distinct rows from People table which contains SearchedName from SearchedPeople table.

SearchedPeople:

```
SearchedName             
--------  
Andrew
John
John Smith
```

People:

```
ID  PersonName      Attribute      Age
----------------------------------------
1   John Smith          1           23
2   John Smith Jr       3           25
3   John Smith Jr II    4           73
4   Kevin               2           21
5   Andrew Smith        1           14
6   Marco               5           90
```

Desired Output:

```
PersonName      Attribute      Age
----------------------------------------
John Smith          1           23
John Smith Jr       3           25
John Smith Jr II    4           73
Andrew Smith        1           14
```

Code i got so far which doesnt wor. It returns three empty rows(why is that?).

```
 SELECT b.PersonName, b.Attribute, b.Age
 FROM SearchedPeople a
 LEFT JOIN People b ON "%"&a.SearchedName&"%" like b.PersonName
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It returns three empty rows because you don't have any columns from table a (`SearchedPeople`) and the `LEFT JOIN` didn't produce a match.

The reason is your criteria is in the wrong order you are searching for `PersonName` in the string `%Searchedname%`  you need to switch that around.  Also Access doesn't like the *%* as much as it likes the **asteriks *** for wilcard unless you make some changes to the query or configuration of MS-Access see below comment from Parafait.

I just tested this:

```
 SELECT a.SearchedName
       ,b.PersonName, b.Attribute, b.Age
 FROM
      SearchedPeople a
       LEFT JOIN People b
       ON  b.PersonName  LIKE ("*" &  a.SearchedName & "*")
```

Edit:

Good Ms Access specific information from a comment from @Parafait pasting in answer in case comment every got deleted.:

Use ALIKE and percents work. And if OP connects to MS Access via OLEDB and not the GUI .exe program, the % operator is required for LIKE statements in coded SQL. OP can also change database settings to ANSI-92 mode to always use % wildcards.

Comment: Use `ALIKE` and percents work. And if OP connects to MS Access via OLEDB and not the GUI .exe program, the `%` operator is required for `LIKE` statements in coded SQL. OP can also change database settings to [ANSI-92 mode](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Comparison-of-Microsoft-Access-SQL-and-ANSI-SQL-93edf744-9070-4af8-bcf9-1953a87bd6e5) to always use `%` wildcards.

Comment: @Parfait thanks I was looking at the ms-access documentation on the wildcards and saw `%` list in the 92 standard and `*` in the 89 but I just went with what I saw working isntead of deep diving to look at why Access wouldn't recognize the `%` anyway thanks for the info, I hope you are good with it, I just pasted your comment directly in the answer to make sure it stays available.  Feel free to edit etc. if you want to change anything.